# Analysis exercise

Tags: integration, analysis

I'm struggling with the following exercise.
Let $f:[0,a] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Prove that
$$
\int_0^a\left ( \int_0^y f(x)\,dx \right )dy=\int_0^a xf(a-x)\,dx
$$
I know that I have to reverse the order of integration but then I can't get the statement.
Somebody can help me?

Comment: Please show us in the question what you get when you *do* change the order of integration.

Comment: What did you get when you reversed the order of integration? If you have done it correctly, you should be a simple substitution away from what you want.

Comment: I get $\int_{0}^{a}\left ( \int_{x}^{a}f(x)dy \right )dx=\int_{0}^{a}(a-x)f(x)dx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can integrate by parts:
$$ \int_0^a \left( \int_0^y f(x) \, dx \right) dy = \left[ (y-a) \int_0^y f(x) \, dx \right]_{y=0}^a + \int_0^a (a-y)f(y) \, dy. $$
The boundary terms both vanish with this choice of antiderivative for $1$, and the latter can be put in the right form by putting $x=a-y$.

Comment: I got it. The exercise is trivial. Thank you very much!